# CiviMail and PHPMailer Issue?

Tags: civimail, mailing

recently I've encountered a strange issue when sending mass mailings by CiviMail. E.g. I have a mail list of 100 people and I send them a newsletter. Later, in the mailing summary, I can see how many people received the mail and how many emails bounced. Due to the issue I am seeing:

```
- Intended recipients 78 
- Mailings delivered 74 (94.87%) 
- Transmission 0
- Answers 0  
- Rejections 0 (0.00%)  
- Requests for discharge 0 (0.00%)
- Requests for resignation 0 (0.00%)
```

As you can see, I had 78 recipients of this mailing but only 74 received the message. I've traced those 4 recipients (I've created groups based on the Intended recipients and delivered mailings and looked for those 4 recipients) - but when I've tried to send the mail to those 4, the mail status is finished but the mailing summary states:

```
- Intended recipients 4
- Mailings delivered 0 (0.00%) 
- Transmission 0
- Answers 0  
- Rejections 0 (0.00%)  
- Requests for discharge 0 (0.00%)
- Requests for resignation 0 (0.00%)
```

I can't find out why the system is not allowing me to send those mailings. The logs are empty. I'm on Drupal 7.69, CiviCRM 5.20 and I'm using PHPMailer + Mosaico.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue?